# How do I connect an MPU6050 sensor to an Arduino MKR WIFI 1010?

Tags: sensors, i2c, mpu6050, mkr1010

I've been trying to connect an MPU6050 to my MKR WIFI 1010 following [these general instructions](https://www.electronicshub.org/getting-started-arduino-mpu6050/) and using the I2CDev library, but I keep running into problems.

For a while the Arduino just didn't show up as connected in the IDE when all the pins were connected, which I think I've gathered was due to a lack of pull-up resistors for the SCL/SDA pins. Adding 10 kOhm pull-up resistors helped a little (in making the Arduino visible) but it would hang when trying to upload the example sketch. 2.2 kOhm resistors seemed to do the trick, where now the example sketches ([MPU6050_DMP6](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/blob/master/Arduino/MPU6050/examples/MPU6050_DMP6/MPU6050_DMP6.ino) or [MPU6050_raw](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/blob/master/Arduino/MPU6050/examples/MPU6050_raw/MPU6050_raw.ino)) can be uploaded. They still fail to read any actual values, however. The raw sketch gives 0 for everything, and the DMP6 sketch prints

```
Initializing I2C devices...
Testing device connections...
MPU6050 connection failed

Send any character to begin DMP programming and demo: 
Initializing DMP...
DMP Initialization failed (code 1)
```

Does anyone know why the sensor still fails to give any measurements? I connect VCC and GND from the sensor to VCC (3.3V) and GND from my Arduino. SCL and SDA from the sensor are connected to VCC via 2.2 kOhm resistors and to the SCL and SDA pins of the Arduino (12 and 11). And INT from the sensor is connected to digital pin 2. (I tried this on a couple other pins like 0 and 1 since it seems from [the tech specs](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/mkr-wifi-1010) that 2 is not an External Interrupt pin, but that didn't change anything.)

The sensor and examples worked without any extra effort on my Arduino Uno, but unfortunately I fried that with a 12V power supply by accident. I'll probably just get another Uno, but I'm curious why this didn't work, if I'm missing something about I2C or the MKR WIFI.

I'll also note that I had to add

```
define #BUFFER_LENGTH 64
```

to wire.h in order to get sketches including I2Cdev to compile (following these [instructions](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=508669.0)).

Comment: Yes, it was defined as 64, good catch. (Edited now.) I did not run any I2C scanner sketch, but I can try that. The wiring for SDA/SCL used a breadboard with both pins from the sensor connected to their own rows, a 2.2 kOhm resistor from each row to the +3.3V column (which itself connects to VCC on both the Arduino and sensor), and jumper cables from those rows to pins 11 and 12 on the Arduino for SDA/SCL respectively. The other wiring is GND (sensor) to negative column on breadboard to GND (Arduino) and INT (sensor) to digital pin 2 (which I wasn't sure about, so I also tried 0 and 1).

Comment: try the I2CScanner sketch without the pullups too

Comment: I'm seeing "I2C device found at address 0x60" and "I2C device found at address 0x6B", regardless of whether anything is plugged into my Arduino. When I tried to connect the sensor without the pull-up resistors, I got the error message "java.io.IOException: jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - COM3; Method name - setEventsMask(); Exception type - Can't set mask" and the orange CHRG light came on (with quick pulsing)

Comment: the MKR1010 has I2C devices on board

Comment: So it never detected the sensor then. Could different pull up resistors help? 4.7 kOhm seems to be a typical value used

Comment: what module with MPU6050 do you have?

Comment: This one from Aukru: https://www.amazon.com/Aukru-Arduino-Accelerometer-6050-Gyroscope/dp/B019SX74TE/

Comment: My hunch is the MPU 6050 is broken. I got a new Arduino Uno and the I2C scanner hangs when the MPU is connected, regardless of whether I have pull-up resistors. (And it worked perfectly fine with no extra pull-up resistors with my previous Arduino Uno before I fried it.) I'll order a new MPU-6050.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sensor was indeed broken, and I had no problems after ordering a new one.